# Tab and Arrow keys behave as if the design view has focus when code view has focus

Tags: vb6

The title describes my problem. I'll be coding away, press the "down" key to move to the next line and instead one of the controls in design view will be selected. If I hit down some more, it will cycle through the controls in design view as if I have the design view window in focus. The focus is not actually shifting to design view though—typing with the letter keys still affects the code view as expected. To complicate things further, I have not noticed any kind of pattern as to when this happens, sometimes this will happen and sometimes it won't.

I'm working on 64-bit Windows 7 Professional.
Clicking Help > About in VB6 gives the following version information:

- Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 (SP6)
- For 32-bit Windows Development
- Version 9782
- VBA: Retail 6.0.9782
- Forms3: 12.0.6307.500

Has anyone encountered this same issue, and if so is there a fix or workaround for it?

Comment: Hmm yeah, that's weird. I don't think it's a known issue. And even if it were, it's unlikely that a fix will be forthcoming… Can you repro this in a clean virtual machine? It may be a Windows 7 compatibility problem.

Comment: Just a question like that: do you have sub-classing code in there?

Comment: What addins do you have installed in the VB6 IDE?